# Mongodb: get only array of post comments from this object

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

So far I achieved is I got the array inside the object and I want the array directly.

Here is my object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5"),
    "description" : "My Post",
    "postLikes" : [ 
        {
            "likesCount" : 0,
            "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com",
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512631701702),
            "updatedOn" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    ],
    "postComments" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "This is first comment",
            "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com",
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764),
            "updatedOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764)
        }
    ],
    "createdOn" : NumberLong(0),
    "updatedOn" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

**My Query is:**

```
db.user_posts.find({_id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")}, {postComments:1})
```

and the result is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5"),
    "postComments" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "This is first comment",
            "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com",
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764),
            "updatedOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764)
        }
    ]
}
```

**What I want is:**

```
 [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "comment" : "This is first comment",
            "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com",
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764),
            "updatedOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764)
        }
    ]
```

**Also I am using MongoRepository in Spring Boot and the query there is:**

```
@Query(value = "{'_id' : ?0}, {'postComments':1}")
```

and it gave me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `"_id":false`

```
db.user_posts.find({
    _id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")
}, {
    postComments: 1,
    "_id": false
})
```

Or `"_id":0`

```
db.user_posts.find({
    _id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")
}, {
    postComments: 1,
    "_id": 0
})
```

If you only want part of your document then you have to make use of aggregation framework. Luckily there is spring support on that.

As vaibhav mentioned already what `find()` returns.

You can solve your problem with aggregation like that:

```
db.user_posts.aggregate([
{ $match: {_id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")}},
{ $unwind: "$postComments"},
{ $project: {
    _id: 0,
    comment: "$postComments.comment",
    likeByEmail: "$postComments.likeByEmail",
    createdOn: "$postComments.createdOn",
    updatedOn: "$postComments.updatedOn"
  }
}
])
```

As proposed by @Veeram you can also do this:

```
db.user_posts.aggregate([
{ $match: {_id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")}},
{ $unwind: "$postComments"},
{ $replaceRoot: {"newRoot":"$postComments"}}
])
```

Comment: {
    "postComments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "comment" : "This is first comment",
            "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com",
            "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764),
            "updatedOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764)
        }
    ]
}

it give me this result. I need the array directly

Comment: [ { "_id" : null, "comment" : "This is first comment", "likeByEmail" : "a@a.com", "createdOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764), "updatedOn" : NumberLong(1512643824764) } ] 
Like this

Comment: I updated the answer with aggregation framework, check it out.

Comment: You can also replace `$project` stage with `$replaceRoot` in 3.4 version. Saves you from explicitly mapping all the fields. Something like `{ $replaceRoot: {"newRoot":"$postComments"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Using find you will never be able to get the array as a result because as per definition:

> the find() method “returns documents,” the method is actually
>   returning a cursor to the documents.

You can apply projections to the result set but it would essentially always return you a document which unfortunately will always be a json and embeds the array as a property.

Same applies to the insert function you can not insert an array by itself it has to be a valid JSON.

```
> db.arrCollection.insert(["name":"myName", "age": 100]);
2017-12-08T13:02:30.492+0530 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this

> db.user_posts.find({_id: ObjectId("5a28e2a1bf22d2a9ddb8f5d5")}, {postComments:1}).then(function(u){return u.postComments;})